# How do you install mod_wsgi?

Tags: server, apache2, django

I ran the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
```

I keep getting this extremely frustrating message

```
ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!
```

Please help.

Comment: sudo a2enmod will give you list of modules installed. Just enable wsgi as said by ajmitch

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `sudo a2enmod wsgi` should enable the module for you once you reload apache, as most modules don't need the mod_ prefix when enabling them.

Comment: i tried `sudo a2enmod wsgi` but even I m still getting the same error. I typed `sudo a2enmod` and these are the choices I got http://dpaste.de/NEIcf/ It does not contain `wsgi`. Is it ok to ask this question here or do I need to post a new question?

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
```

add the next string to the file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

save, then

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: And how to test this?

Comment: not sure there is some `test_mode_wsgi` script.. just point apache to your wsgi application (check the docs of your framework how to do it), and check if it works..

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: The following command will install wgsi module

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Step 2: To enable the wsgi module run the following command

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Step 3: Restart your apache server by running

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Step 4: Check whether the module is loaded

```
sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Use `sudo` for `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the wsgi.load and wsgi.conf from mods-available to mods-enabled manually and then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

### WSGI Warning

[Official WSGI documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#virtual-environment-and-python-version) says:

> When using a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi, it is very important that it has been created using the same Python installation that mod_wsgi was originally compiled for.

And then:

> It is **not possible** to use a Python virtual environment to force mod_wsgi to use a different Python version,
>    or even a **different Python installation**. In other words, Python interpreter is embedded within the mod_wsgi.

So I would not recommend any of precompiled mod_wsgi binaries from `apt` but instead you can compile it following the official [installation docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html).

### The other way

Use https://gunicorn.org/ and an Apache's

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
```

directive in your virtualhost config.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Related:

- [Apache shows Python code instead of execute it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1495769/1157209)