# Apache shows Python code instead of execute it

Tags: python, apache2

VPS server running Ubuntu 22.04, Apache 2.4.18 and Python 3.5.2

When I try to access a webpage on that server it shows python code instead of execute it...

Last guide I tried was this: https://howtoforge.es/como-ejecutar-scripts-de-python-con-apache-y-mod-wsgi-en-ubuntu-20-04/

But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Install wsgi

On Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3, you have to install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Configure your vhost

Your manual mentions creating a new vhost config `/etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf`. However, this is not required and if you don't have other sites on the server, you can use the default Apache config: `/etc/apache2/conf-available/000-default.conf`. Add the following line before the  line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias ​​/wsgi /var/www/html/wsgy.py
```

Don't forget to restart the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Create Python script

To configure `mod_wsgi`, you have to create a Python script that will be served by the Apache web server: `sudo nano /var/www/html/wsgi.py`. The example `wsgi.py` in your manual is returning error 500, so you can use this code instead:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!\n'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

#### Accessing the Python site

- To access the Python file, you should use `http://your-server-ip/wsgi` or whatever alias you configured in your vhost's file.
- Opening `http://your-server-ip/wsgi.py` will still return Python code instead of execute it.

Comment: ok, that seems to work, thanks!.. but im still have some problems, http://your-server-ip/wsgi this works, executes the script without problem.  But i have this line in my index.html : <form action="/interfaz1" method="post"> without .py i got an NOT FOUND error, with .py after interfaz1 i got the code again.

Comment: @Art If `interfaz1` is another Python file with name `interfaz1.py`, you can add it to your vhost file like `WSGIScriptAlias ​​/interfaz1 /var/www/html/interfaz1.py`. Don't forget to restart the Apache after you add the line.

Comment: do i have to add a line for each python file?; what about a python application with many files?

Comment: @Art It depends on how you structure your project.This is something that can be better answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).